# How to add delay in onchange event in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have below input field in LWC

HTML:

```html
<lightning-input variant="label-hidden" type="number"
    data-key={lineItem.lineItemId} label="percentageValue"
    onchange={percentageChange} style="width: 85px;"
    placeholder="Percente" step="0.01">
```

JS:

```javascript
percentageChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

If I press 123 in the input text box, I get console log as:

1

12

123

... instead of just 123. Can anyone please suggest, how to add a little delay so that the onchange only picks up the value, when user has finished typing?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't "delay" the event explicitly (though some browsers may choose to only fire them periodically), but you could build in a delay for potentially expensive processing:

```
onChangeHandler(event) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId); // no-op if invalid id
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(this.doExpensiveThing.bind(this), 500); // Adjust as necessary
}
doExpensiveThing() {
    // Do something here
}
```

This example code will wait until no new changes have occurred for at least half a second.

Alternatively, you can use Arrow functions to remember `this` as well:

```
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>this.doExpensiveThing(), 500); // Adjust as necessary
```

If you need to pass parameters, you can pass them as additional parameters to `bind`, or directly in the parameter list if using an arrow function:

```
setTimeout(this.doExpensiveThing.bind(this, param1, param2), 500);
setTimeout(()=>this.doExpensiveThing(param1, param2), 500);
```

Edit: [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/bdt8x1gt/1/edit), [LWC Recipes Example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/productFilter/productFilter.js)

Comment: thank you so much for responding, could you please confirm if this will increase the performance of the page, or it will add an extra load on the page, is it a best practice to use delay or is t fine if onchange is working on every single character I type.

Comment: @gs650x If you're doing something expensive (hitting the server, rendering thousands of items, etc), the delay will make the page much more responsive, otherwise it doesn't matter.

Comment: A working example you can find in this [lwc reciepes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/ebikes-lwc/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/productFilter/productFilter.js)

Comment: @sanketkumar Thanks for that, I edited it in as well as a very short playground example I just wrote for this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sfdcfox and @sanketkumar

Comment: @sfdcfox you're a champ

Comment: @sfdcfox how can I pass the event as a parameter to `doExpensiveThing()`?

Comment: @Meryem Additional parameters can be passed in to bind as parameters. For example: `this.doExpensiveThing.bind(this, { event })` would pass the event received as a parameter to the method being called. Also, this answer could also be supplemented with an alternative: `this.timeoutId = setTimeout(()=>this.doExpensiveThing(event), 500)`; the arrow function remembers `this` so you don't have to call bind.

Comment: @Meryem I edited some additional examples into the answer that should address your comment.