# Methods are not available until the component is rendered

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, rerender

I need to call lwc @api method after aura component initialised (it's a quick action). However, on init the lwc is not rendered yet and I get the `Methods are not available until the component is rendered` warning in console (method call itself fails quietly, ugh).

I've tried using `aura:doneRendering` but that is deprecated and gets called multiple times. Is there a way to call aura method once only after render?

Note: I need to use both aura and lwc for some API's are not available in either.

Edit: I've tried with `<aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>` which works ok, BUT there's use case where this component is extended - that's when init doesn't work.

Edit 2: Solved with window.setTimeout of 1ms and using init...

Answer (score -1):

You can use [connectedCallback()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom) in LWC to make the method call. It will only be called after the LWC renders.

Example Code:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class LifeCycle extends LightningElement {
   connectedCallback(){
        //do something
   }    
}
```

Note: `connectedCallback()` in Lightning Web Component flows from parent to child. If you have a parent and child component, `connectedCallback()` defined in parent component will get fired first.

[More Info](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/12/13/connectedcallback-in-lightning-web-component/).

Comment: I’ve tried this before before exposing method as an api. Problem with connectedCallback it only works on first render, which means if you click quick action second time it won’t execute.

Comment: @dzh Try adding a delay so that you give time for the component to load - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286872/how-to-add-delay-in-onchange-event-in-lwc

Comment: That wouldn't solve the key issue with your solution, but did solve in aura, as per my edit.